# What is the current size of near blockchain and expected to be?

Tags: nearprotocol

1. I wanted to know the size of Near blockchain
2. https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc - Is this officlal apis exposed and will have a long term support

Answer (score 3):

1. Size on disk or what? mainnet network archival node storing the full history is 720GB on disk, while RPC nodes storing only the recent 5 epochs of history take 103GB on disk.
2. Yes, it is official APIs that are maintained with long-term support in mind (except the `EXPERIMENTAL_`-prefixed ones)